# Smooth morphism of relative dimension $>0$ and fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth morphisms of relative dimension $>0$ of two smooth (affine) varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. I wonder if the corresponding holomorphic map of the corresponding complex manifolds can be a fiber bundle, i.e. the holomorphic map $f_{an}:X_{an}\to Y_{an}$ is a fiber bundle. I know $f$ is a submersion thus $f_{an}$ is a submersion too. But by an exercise of Hartshorne, a proper map between affine varieties is finite. In my case, $f,f_{an}$ are not finite, which implies $f$ is not proper, so it seems (I am not very sure) $f_{an}$ is not proper. But by Ehresmann's lemma: a proper surjective submersion is a locally trivial fibration. I wonder if it would make $f_{an}:X_{an}\to Y_{an}$ not a fiber bundle?

Comment: Please include your definition of a fiber bundle.

Comment: @KReiser just the usual definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $f:X\to Y$ a morphism of separated schemes of finite type over $\Bbb C$, $f$ is proper if and only if $f_{an}$ is proper by SGA 1 XII.3.2. So $f_{an}$ cannot be proper in your case, which means the hypotheses of Ehresmann's lemma are not satisfied and you cannot apply it.

A readily-available example of a smooth map of positive relative dimension of affine varieties which is not analytically a fiber bundle is the projection $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C[x,y,(x^2-y^2)^{-1}]\to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C[x]$. This is smooth because it is the composition of an open immersion and the standard smooth map $\Bbb A^2_\Bbb C \to \Bbb A^1_\Bbb C$, and its analytification is not a fiber bundle because the fiber over any point which is not the origin is a twice-punctured complex plane, while the fiber over the origin is a once-punctured complex plane.

Comment: Is there any sense that we can see a smooth morphism as a fiber bundle? So far I can only see a smooth morphism as a submersion, but I saw somewhere in overflow that people said smooth morphism is a counterpart of fiber bundle

Comment: I am a little confused, suppose $X$ is also complete then $f_{an}$ is a map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space thus proper, which is like a contradiction, moreover by Ehresmann's lemma it's a fiber bundle.

Comment: A smooth morphism on the algebraic geometry side should be thought of as a submersion on the differential geometry side. Ehresmann's lemma provides the correct additional criteria to get you from a smooth map to a locally trivial fibration (once you take an analytification). Without further details about the statement you "saw somewhere" it will be difficult to say more. Your second comment also does not make sense to me - if you're taking $X$ to be both complete and affine, then it's finite, so I don't really know what you're after here.